# Separator insets for table section header

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I have an `UITableView` (style = `UITableView.Style.plain`) with rather simple cells. In IB I set cell's separator inset as custom:

[image]

Also, I set table section header as follows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let label = UILabel()
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.backgroundColor = .white
    label.text = "My table section"
    return label
}
```

The result is:

[image]

I want to remove separator between "My table section" and "cell 0". How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default separator of the tableview if you don't want it you can set it to none.

[image]

And if you want separators under the cell you have to make one by yourself. Just add a view in your cell under the label and give its constraints like leading-trailing top-bottom and height(how much thick separator you want in my opinion maybe 1.5), that should do the job.